# Android HTML Viewer Opening a .xlsx

Tags: html, android

I am viewing a local HTML page in the Android KitKat 4.4 HTML Viewer app that comes pre installed. In the HTML file I have links to PDF's on the storage device and one link to an excel sheet (.xlsx) which is opened with WPS (From the Play Store). When I click a PDF it opens but when I click the excel sheet it does nothing. If I open this HTML file in Firefox it will work, just not on the default HTML Viewer. Any suggestions?

```
<a href="TechTimeSheet.xlsx"><img alt="Tech Time Sheet NEW" src="_templates/frame/graphics/Icons/iconpdf.png" class="theImage"/><br/>
<nobr>Tech Time Sheet NEW</nobr>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the full path in the href tag?  Also, where is the closing anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

HTML Viewer is not a fully-functional browser app but has a number of quirks and limitations.

According to its [source code](https://gitorious.org/0xdroid/packages_apps_htmlviewer/source/ae36e6ba1ad74a7eb844a41c6c0fc1ecd3c66467:src/com/android/htmlviewer), when you send it a `file:` Uri, it wraps it inside a content provider before giving it to the `WebView`. I don't see any code that would reverse that process, so presumably those PDF and XLSX files also end up being opened through that content provider. Different apps have different degrees of support for `content:` Uris, and the HTML Viewer content provider itself is pretty barebones, thus it is unsurprising that it doesn't work that well.